# xslt copy child note and add extra nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath, copy

For the following xml:

```
<root>
    <employees>
        <employee>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
            <Dept>CS</Dept>
            <Designation>sse</Designation>
        </employee>
    </employees>
</root>
```

I use this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Name">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <Age>34</Age>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Dept">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <Domain>Insurance</Domain>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to achieve the following output

```
   <employee>
       <Name>ABC</Name>
       <Age>34</Age>
       <Dept>CS</Dept>
       <Domain>Insurance</Domain>
       <Designation>sse</Designation>
   </employee>
```

I don't know what xpath shall I use to limit the result only to employee node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, processing starts at the document node (root node) denoted by `/` thus if you write a template

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//employee"/>
</xsl:template>
```

you only process any `employee` descendants of the document with the rest of the templates.

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHT6 for a working demo of above suggestion integrated into your stylesheet, the whole code is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Name">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <Age>34</Age>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Dept">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <Domain>Insurance</Domain>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//employee"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: looks fine what else  should I add to have the output surrounded by <employee> node (would like to avoid hard coding this)

Comment: You can add the template I posted to your stylesheet you have and add `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` and `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, that suffices to get the result you say you want. Not sure where exactly you want to avoid the use of the name of the element `employee`.